# Fyber test for AppLovin and Mopup return "Missing Permissions"

Tags: android, applovin, heyzap, fyber

I'm trying to integrate AppLovin and MoPup through the Fyber mediator.

The integration of the sdk is correct. But both return in the Fyber test that "Missing Permissions."

I have reviewed all of Fyber's documentation again.

I have implemented all the permissions in the Android Studio manifest.

I have checked that both advertising networks are active in the Fyber panel.

I contacted Apploving and they told me that the permits I have are correct. It could be Fyber's thing.

Permissions implemented in AndroidManifest.

`````
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- Required by AdMob, AppLovin, and Heyzap Ad Network -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- Required by AppLovin -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- Required by Tapjoy -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- Required by MoPub -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Optionally used by Heyzap Ad Network, and MoPub -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />````



I hoped that with those permits the test was correct.

But the Fyber test is telling me that "Missing Permissions"
`````

Comment: Hello! I tried with Api 28 and the Fyber test continues showing "Missing Permissions".

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve this problem with help of this post:

[Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

I add this code.

```
    public  boolean checkPermission() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 Error de permiso. Tienes permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*Timber.tag(LOG_TAG).e("Permission error. You have permission");*/
                return true;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2 Error de permiso. Has pedido permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /* Timber.tag(LOG_TAG).e("Permission error. You have asked for permission");*/
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            // for a stuff below api level 23
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3 Error de permiso. Ya tienes el permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*Timber.tag(LOG_TAG).e("Permission error. You already have the permission");*/
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Versions up to 23 needs to have specific permission of the user.